# Display a popup (getFeatureInfo) with Leaflet

Tags: geoserver, leaflet, popup, getfeatureinfo

I want to display WMS layers in a webmapping application built with Leaflet (version 0.7). Layers (ArcGIS shape format) are stored in GeoServer (version 2.10.0) in a public domain workspace. I got it and I can visualize the layers in my application.

I also want to display a custom popup with information about each layer when I click on the layer in the webmapping application. This information I want to show is what is stored in the attribute table of each shape layer. I am not able to display this information in the application.

Can someone tell me an example code or how to do it?